# Opencv IMWRITE_JPEG_LUMA_QUALITY parameter doesn't work as expected in 3.2.0

Tags: c++, opencv, image-compression

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga292d81be8d76901bff7988d18d2b42aca64c65da14d74ab87143d6999c4df12ea), the IMWRITE_JPEG_LUMA_QUALITY parameter is supported.

> IMWRITE_JPEG_LUMA_QUALITY     Separate luma quality level, 0 - 100, default is 0 - don't use.

But I realized that when I set it to default 0 (don't use), it still has an impact on the image. This is unexpected, if it's set to 0, it shouldn't have any impact on the image compression.

[image]

[image]

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-imwrite-jpeg-luma-quality-parameter-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-3-2-0/8370

Comment: Related: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21857